# boost asio channels "no type named 'receive_cancelled_signature'"

Tags: boost, boost-asio, c++20

I'm trying to implement a thread safe observer design pattern using boost so I want to iterate over a list of boost asio channels?

Say I have

```
struct A{};

std::list<boost::asio::experimental::channel<void(std::error_code, std::shared_ptr<A>>> channels;

for (auto it = channels.begin(); it != channels.end(); ++it)
{}
```

Using this code I got :

```
error, no type named 'receive_cancelled_signature'.
```

When I remove the for loop, the program compiles without errors
Is it possible to iterate over channels in boost asio ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler repro: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35e540935baf06ee)

```
#include <boost/asio/experimental/channel.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/system_executor.hpp>

using Channel = boost::asio::experimental::channel<void(std::error_code, size_t)>;

int main() {
    Channel c(boost::asio::system_executor{});
}
```

`shared_ptr`, `A`, `list` and the loop had nothing to do with it.

Your mistake is that you use `std::error_code` which isn't supported by default.

Standalone Asio does use `std::error_code`, and perhaps Boost Asio can be configured to do so.

> Keep in mind that Boost System has more features, and excellent interop with std::error_code these days.

### Fix

[Use `boost::system::error_code`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/channels.html):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/956ada296e14d7bc)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/channel.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using Channel = boost::asio::experimental::channel<void(boost::system::error_code, size_t)>;


int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;

    std::list<Channel> channels;

    for (auto n = 5; n--;)
        channels.emplace_back(ctx);

    for (Channel& ch : channels) {
        std::cout << "Ch at address " << &ch << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Ch at address 0x2047d90
Ch at address 0x2048130
Ch at address 0x2048470
Ch at address 0x20487b0
Ch at address 0x2048af0
```